# Visualize average asset condition over time

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

I have 3300 road inspection records summarized in a SQL query:

```
YEAR    AVG CONDITION   CLASS   ROAD_COUNT
----    -------------   -----   ----------
2013         8.0          A        300
2014         7.8          A        300
2015         7.3          A        300
2016         7.3          A        300
2017         7.1          A        300
2018         7.1          A        300
2019         7.1          A        300
2020         6.8          A        300
2021         6.5          A        300
2022         5.9          A        300

2013         9.0          B        500
2014         8.8          B        500
2015         8.3          B        500
2016         8.3          B        500
2017         8.3          B        500
2018         8.2          B        500
2019         8.1          B        500
2020         7.8          B        500
2021         7.5          B        500
2022         6.7          B        500

2013         8.5          C        2500
2014         8.3          C        2500
2015         7.7          C        2500
2016         7.8          C        2500
2017         7.7          C        2500
2018         7.6          C        2500
2019         7.6          C        2500
2020         7.2          C        2500
2021         7.0          C        2500
2022         6.2          C        2500
```

---

**Question:**

It's difficult to see patterns in the data when it's in table form. I want to visualize the data in a graph/chart so that my users can make sense of the data.

What's an appropriate way to visualize the data?

For example, is a line graph a suitable choice?

[image]

Related posts:

- [User Experience: Visualize average asset condition over time](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/144061/visualize-average-asset-condition-over-time)
- [Stacked bar chart to show asset maintenance types by year](https://superuser.com/questions/1735583/stacked-bar-chart-to-show-asset-maintenance-types-by-year)

Comment: What would be a meaningful or useful "pattern"?  Who is your audience?  What is the purpose of the visualization?

Comment: A line graph seems to work fairly well for your data. I wouldn't insist on displaying zero on the $y$ axis. More at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184525/how-to-determine-whether-or-not-the-y-axis-of-a-graph-should-start-at-zero